# Is MLF a fair scheduling protocol?

Tags: c, process, cpu

Is MLF(multiple level feedback) a fair protocol? does it favor any types of jobs in particular? short/long? does it cause performance issues?

Comment: You will also need to define fair. A reference link to define your idea of MLF would also be useful.

Comment: Sounds like a question straight out of CPS346: Operating Systems.

Comment: Haha it does. But no, I am just catching up on my systems knowledge. That's what a geek does on week nights. hah

Answer (score 0):

In general they prefer short jobs (or I/O bound jobs). Since your question is broad, I'd suggest you read a summary of the linux implementation of this on [IBM's website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-scheduler/). Linux has moved on to a red-black queue based scheduler ([completely fair scheduler](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler/)).